# What are my troubleshooting options for Hyperbus RAM?

Tags: stm32, spi, ram

I have a custom PCB with a [STM32H7A3ZI](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32h7a3zi.html) MCU, and a [S27KL0642S27KS0642](https://www.cypress.com/part/s27ks0642gabhi030) Hyperbus RAM.

My code, as well as the app note ([AN5050](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00407776-octospi-interface-on-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf)) I'm following sets up the RAM for memory mapped access.

I believe I've wired and configured it correctly, but it's not working. I'll get into the specifics of how I set it up in a minute, but my primary question is: How can I get some error messages or something to tell me what's happening?

The setup doesn't result in any errors, but accessing the RAM locks up the chip so hard that it can't be reprogrammed using the ST-Link V2. I have to hold the boot pin high while power cycling the chip to get it to take a program again.

I'm using the STM32cubeIDE, and I can debug. I'm also using the HAL libraries, and the cubeMX configuratior. I can't probe the signals easily.

I've been scrutinizing and experimenting with every setting, but I think guess and check might not be enough to solve this.

**Additional Info:**

The trace lengths are between 0.62in and 0.97in, except for CS which I (perhaps naively) allowed to be 1.3in.

I've noticed that if I program this firmware onto an older PCB that does not have the RAM chip, it doesn't lock up.

Here's my setup code:

```
void MX_OCTOSPI1_Init(void)
{
    OSPIM_CfgTypeDef sOspiManagerCfg = {0};
    OSPI_HyperbusCfgTypeDef sHyperBusCfg = {0};

    hospi1.Instance = OCTOSPI1;
    hospi1.Init.FifoThreshold = 4;
    hospi1.Init.DualQuad = HAL_OSPI_DUALQUAD_DISABLE;
    hospi1.Init.MemoryType = HAL_OSPI_MEMTYPE_HYPERBUS;
    hospi1.Init.DeviceSize = 23;
    hospi1.Init.ChipSelectHighTime = 1;
    hospi1.Init.FreeRunningClock = HAL_OSPI_FREERUNCLK_DISABLE;
    hospi1.Init.ClockMode = HAL_OSPI_CLOCK_MODE_0;
    hospi1.Init.WrapSize = HAL_OSPI_WRAP_NOT_SUPPORTED;
    hospi1.Init.ClockPrescaler = 2;
    hospi1.Init.SampleShifting = HAL_OSPI_SAMPLE_SHIFTING_NONE;
    hospi1.Init.DelayHoldQuarterCycle = HAL_OSPI_DHQC_ENABLE;
    hospi1.Init.ChipSelectBoundary = 0;
    hospi1.Init.ClkChipSelectHighTime = 0;
    hospi1.Init.DelayBlockBypass = HAL_OSPI_DELAY_BLOCK_BYPASSED;
    hospi1.Init.MaxTran = 0;
    hospi1.Init.Refresh = 100;
    if (HAL_OSPI_Init(&hospi1) != HAL_OK)
    {
         Error_Handler();
    }

    sOspiManagerCfg.ClkPort = 2;
    sOspiManagerCfg.DQSPort = 1;
    sOspiManagerCfg.NCSPort = 2;
    sOspiManagerCfg.IOLowPort = HAL_OSPIM_IOPORT_2_LOW;
    sOspiManagerCfg.IOHighPort = HAL_OSPIM_IOPORT_1_LOW;

    sOspiManagerCfg.Req2AckTime = 1;

    if (HAL_OSPIM_Config(&hospi1, &sOspiManagerCfg, HAL_OSPI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    sHyperBusCfg.RWRecoveryTime = 4;
    sHyperBusCfg.AccessTime = 6;
    sHyperBusCfg.WriteZeroLatency = HAL_OSPI_LATENCY_ON_WRITE;
    sHyperBusCfg.LatencyMode = HAL_OSPI_FIXED_LATENCY;
    if (HAL_OSPI_HyperbusCfg(&hospi1, &sHyperBusCfg, HAL_OSPI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE) != HAL_OK)
    {
         Error_Handler();
    }

    /* Memory-mapped mode setup */
    OSPI_HyperbusCmdTypeDef sCommand = { 0 };
    OSPI_MemoryMappedTypeDef sMemMappedCfg = { 0 };

    /* Memory-mapped mode configuration --------------------------------------- */
    sCommand.AddressSpace = HAL_OSPI_MEMORY_ADDRESS_SPACE;
    sCommand.AddressSize  = HAL_OSPI_ADDRESS_32_BITS;
    sCommand.DQSMode      = HAL_OSPI_DQS_ENABLE;
    sCommand.Address      = 0;
    sCommand.NbData       = 1;
    if( HAL_OSPI_HyperbusCmd( &hospi1, &sCommand, HAL_OSPI_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE ) != HAL_OK )
    {
         Error_Handler();
    }

    sMemMappedCfg.TimeOutActivation = HAL_OSPI_TIMEOUT_COUNTER_DISABLE;

    if( HAL_OSPI_MemoryMapped( &hospi1, &sMemMappedCfg ) != HAL_OK )
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }

}
```

And (somewhat redacted) schematic:

[image: schematic]

**Further Debugging:**

I desoldered the ram (BGA) and attempted to connect #CLK to gnd using a hair of wire before re-soldering it. I'm not sure if it worked, and furthermore I may have broken other connections in the process.

I have changed my code to use indirect (manual) operation instead of memory mapping. This at least prevents the chip from locking up when the ram does not work correctly.

With the clock speed at 200MHz (the rating of the RAM), I can read register zero, and the value is close to what the datasheet says it should be.

Expected 00 0 01100 1000 0001

Read     10 0 01000 1000 0001 (reads the same every time)

Attempting to access a register address higher than 0 returns the same value up to address 30, where the read starts to fail. According to the datasheet, I should get a value of 1 for register 1.

I can't get it to work with the clock divider increased even to 2. I still get values sometimes but they're even farther from "correct" (if that matters). I experimented with almost every setting.

I slowed down clock to 1MHz, and tapped the signals with a logic analyzer. The address seems to be transmitted correctly by the MCU, although the address is always divided by 2 compared with the register. This sort of makes sense, since the MCU Hyperbus peripheral manual says only even addresses are allowed, due to the 2 byte per transaction protocol.

The RWDS line is the only one that doesn't appear to be behaving correctly, although I'm not sure.

*This is an attempted read of address 2, with the clock reduced to 1MHz*
[image: 1 MHz read address 2]

Note the first 6 clock edges, which correspond to the command/address portion of the transaction.

Comment: I'd say the only true way would be to hook up a logic analyzer and check the timings… hyperbus is only a little more than a quad SPI. Try to lower the clock if possible to check if it gets better. I've no experience with the ST but check if your bus controller module has some exception or interrupt to signal

Comment: Have you confirmed the hardware is correct? Are the pins connected? How have you proven this? If you can’t prove the basics, then you’re relying on the good Lord to help you and he’s not too good with electronics.

Comment: Its bga, so I cant directly test the connections.

Comment: If you have series resistors you can measure the protection diodes to confirm connection. Or get it xrayed.

Comment: Well I've found one mistake. In the fine print of the datasheet I noticed: "Tie the CK# input pin to either VccQ or VssQ if not connected to the host controller, but do not leave it floating." ..but I have left it floating. I wonder if this is the issue? Unfortunately it is difficult to fix.

Comment: Is there a way you can build an intermediate prototype that breaks out the BGA, so you can actually work at getting this running in a package that you can work on?

Comment: @ScottSeidman That's my current plan. I'm going to include inline resistors this time too so that I can check the BGA connections.